# Discovering new bluetooth devices

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I created a small project to search for Bluetooth devices, but it doesn’t work.

```
MainActivity.java

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private BluetoothAdapter mBTA;
    private SingBroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
    private ArrayAdapter aAdapter;
    private ListView out;


    int REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH=1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //register local BT adapter
        mBTA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        //check to see if there is BT on the Android device at all
        if (mBTA == null){
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth not supported", duration).show();
        }
        //let's make the user enable BT if it isn't already
        if (!mBTA.isEnabled()){
            Intent enableBT = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBT, REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH);
        }
        //cancel any prior BT device discovery
        if (mBTA.isDiscovering()){
            mBTA.cancelDiscovery();
        }
        //re-start discovery
        mBTA.startDiscovery();

        //let's make a broadcast receiver to register our things
        mReceiver = new SingBroadcastReceiver();
        IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, ifilter);
        out = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.simpleListView);

    }

    private class SingBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction(); //may need to chain this to a recognizing function
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                String derp = device.getName() + " - " + device.getAddress();
                aAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                out.setAdapter(aAdapter);

            }
        }
    }
}


activity_main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/simpleListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

There is nothing displayed in the main activity, a blank screen. The list of devices should be displayed during the creation of the activity in the oncreate method. I tested this application on my phone, it does not work. The list of devices is not displayed. Before this, the application asks you to turn on Bluetooth on the device. This is my first serious project, so don't judge too harshly. Maybe I did something wrong, I can’t figure it out.

Comment: Where you initialize your ArrayAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize the arratAdapter befor you add items

```
aAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
```

further, bluetooth discovery is an asynchronous, you should listen to it results .

Comment: Thank you. How to listen to the results? With a button?